# Using apex:slds tag, styles do not show

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I am trying to convert from using `SLDS` as a static resource and use the `<apex:slds/>` element in a visualforce page instead. I am on a sandbox that is on Spring '17 and the page is version 39.0. When I load it I can see the min'ed resource coming across the network tab in my browser dev console. I can also do the following to get the non-minified resource:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
```

The only differences in one particular class style that I notice is demonstrated below:

**CSS From Static Resource (expected display results):**

```
.slds .slds-text-heading--large {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1.25; }
```

**CSS From SLDS Asset import (not expected display results):**

```
.slds-scope .slds-text-heading--large {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 1.25; }
```

I just chose one particular style to demonstrate my issue. But none of the styling is happening on the page. I feel like I am missing something simple, but I am having issues pinpointing it.

**Display with Static Resource:**

[image]

**Display with `<apex:slds />`:**

[image]

Comment: Did you apply the `slds-scope` class to your container element? It might help to include the markup for this header.

Comment: of course I didn't, but that opened up a whole new issue. Thanks @AdrianLarson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you apply the scoping class!

```
<apex:slds />
<div class="slds-scope">
    <!-- header markup -->
</div>
```